# How to set the origin for a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a div that follows the mouse cursor on my screen. This is done by handling the document `mousemove` event and setting its `left` and `top` position based on the event data.

For this example let's say it has a width and height of 10.

It is desired for it to always be centered on the cursor. To make this happen the `left` and `top` need to be horizontally offset by half of div's width and vertically offset by half of the div's height. This allows it to be perfectly centered on the mouse cursor.

`document.querySelector(".circle").style.left = e.x - (width / 2)`

However, this is done in many places in the application and it seems cumbersome. Is it possible to instead set the origin such that when I set the `left` and `top` properties, I do not need to offset by half the width and height, since the origin would be at the center of the div?

The only thing I could find was the `transform-origin` property, but this seems to only apply to the `transform` CSS properties, and not properties like `left`, `margin-left`, etc.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

This calculates the percentage from the width and height of the element itself.

Example snippet:

```js
const move = document.getElementById("move")
const mouseMoveHandler = e => {
  move.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  move.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler)
```

```css
#move {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="move">I follow the cursor</div>
```

Comment: `transform` is a good way to do it too if you don't have to support older browsers, and it is GPU-accelerated.

Answer (score 1):

You can offset it *absolutely* relative to a parent who is 0x0 and positioned *relatively*, and further make the parent move with your mouse.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .origin {
            position: relative;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
         } 

         .circle {
            position: absolute;
            top: -10px;
            right: -10px;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 3px solid red;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div class="origin">
         <div class="circle"/>
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

See more details: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Oh, this is a decent idea. Cool, I might do this. Probably not as elegant as just having an `origin` CSS property, but still works.